# How to filter in many-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Since I could not find the exact answer for me, I decided to ask. 
I have the following two models:

```
class Schedule(models.Model): 
     transport = models.ForeignKey(Transport) 
     stop = models.ForeignKey(Stop) 
     from_to_stop = models.ForeignKey(Direction) 
     time = models.ManyToManyField(TimeTable) 
     type_day = models.ForeignKey(TypeDay) 

     created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created at'), auto_now_add = True) 
     updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Modified at'), auto_now = True) 


class TimeTable(models.Model): 
     time_arrival = models.TimeField() 

     created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created at'), auto_now_add = True) 
     updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Modified at'), auto_now = True)
```

A script that must be dynamically added things in '`time`' field on the '`Schedule`'. Here's what I do:

```
time = self.get_or_create_time(time) 
count = Schedule.objects.filter(time__in = [time]).count() 
if not count: 
    schedule.time.add(time)


def get_or_create_time(self, time):
    obj, created = TimeTable.objects.get_or_create(time_arrival=time)
    return obj
```

Here I'm not getting the required result for me, because it searches the entire table if there is such a connection somewhere. I want to see if there is such a link only for the current object ' `schedule` ' is the current object. All I want is for him to see whether there is a connection with the ' `TimeTable` '. How to do this in Django?

Comment: This is not very clear (quite apart from your horrible habit of putting spaces before parentheses). What does `get_or_create_time` do? Why are you using an `__in` lookup with a single time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, there is no point in using `__in` with a single element which you then wrap in a list. The fact that you had to do that should have given you a hint that you are using the wrong predicate: just use the default (which is `__eq`, but since it's the default you can leave it out altogether).

Also, if you only want to know if an object exists, use `.exists()` rather than `.count()`, as the latter is a more expensive query if there can be multiple objects.

But basically your problem is simple. You want to filter the times belonging to a schedule: so, start with that schedule, not the whole Schedule model.

```
exists = self.times.filter(time_arrival=time.time_arrival).exists()
```